# adding background image to XWPF paragraph

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

We are trying to create a dynamic word document using apache poi-ooxml libraries, but unfortunately it is still in developing mode. Can any one tell me how I can add a back ground image to a XWPFParagraph.

Comment: There is nothing like a "background image to a paragraph" in `Word`. A paragraph can only have background color. There are watermarks possible but for the whole page. And there are pictures placed behind the text possible. But this is also not related to one paragraph only but to the whole text over the size of the picture. So what exactly is you requirement? `Apache poi` cannot do what `Word` itself not can do and what is not able to be stored into the `*.docx` file.

Comment: @AxelRichter thanks for the answer. I found a solution by breaking a image into tiles and filling them into the table cells as per our need.